# Is it correct to say: "I would do something, be it me"?

Tags: conditionals, subjunctive-mood

I mean that "I would do something, if it only were me. But it was not me, so I've done nothing".

Comment: Imagine a situation. Your friend tells you: "Hi! Yesterday I saw you in a crowd. You saw me too but suddenly ran away." And you reply to him: "I would surely greet you, be it me."

Comment: Probably, I have constructed my phrase by analogy with "be it so" and "be it a cat or a dog".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. It sounds old-fashioned, but searching through Google books for such phrases used in the 1800s, I did not find a single instance of anybody using "be it me" or "be it I" in this way. What you're looking for is "were it me" or "were it I"; this usage requires the past subjunctive and not the present subjunctive. Here are some examples:

> Why, were it me, I'd take it just to spite him.
>
> Were it me, I'd show him the difference.
>
> Were it me, I do believe I'd be half inclined to stay, and be discovered.
>
> "Were it I," said the second man, with a shrug of his shoulders, "I'd get it to the Admiral,"
>
> I can make nothing of it, Roland, but were it I, I should ask my mother exactly what it means.
>
> Were it I that sold that poor perished victim his drams, I should seem to hear his voice mingling its wailings with the storms of every bleak wintry night.

Some grammarian prescriptivists would say that it should be "were it I", but both forms seem to have been used. This is still an old-fashioned way of saying this, and I recommend saying "if it were I" or (maybe less grammatical, but more common) "if it was me" unless you want to sound like you're speaking archaic English.

Comment: ‘Traditional grammar calls our irrealis a “past subjunctive”, contrasting with “present subjunctive’ ‘be’. But there are no grounds for analysing this “were” as a past tense counterpart of the “be” that we find in constructions like “It’s vital that he be kind to her.” (Huddleston and Pullum, authors of ‘The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language’.

Comment: They're right: "It had been vital that he be kind to her," not "that he were ..." So what do they recommend calling these verb forms? The *irrealis* and ... ?

Comment: In the sentence 'It’s vital that he be kind to her', they call 'be' 'subjunctive'. They continue 'We don't use "subjunctive" as a term for an inflectional category, but for a syntactic construction employing the plain form of the verb.'

Answer (score 3):

In such cases, you use the past subjunctive, which is used for imaginary or hypothetical conditions. The present subjunctive is used to express commands or requests.

> If I were rich I would live on Long Island.

This sentence express a hypothetical condition, as I am not rich.

> I demand she be on time.

This sentence express an order. The verbs that express an order, and that generally use the subjunctive are *ask*, *demand*, *insist*, *recommend*, *request*, and *require*.

To notice that the past subjunctive is not called so because it is used for an event happened in the past, nor is the present subjunctive called so because it is used for an event that happens in the present.

Comment: So for conditionals like "If it is cold, I will wear a coat", why do we use *is*, the indicative, and not *be*, the subjunctive?  Its being cold is still a hypothetical situation, right?

Comment: @Jez: not all of us do (at least in writing).

Comment: I don’t find it helpful to think of the English subjunctive in terms of past and present. The authors of ‘The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language’ go so far as to deny that this use of ‘were’ is subjunctive at all.

Comment: Probably, I have constructed my phrase by analogy with "be it so" and "be it a cat or a dog". May it be an archaic form?

Answer (score 3):

You could say: "**I would do something, were it I**"; you might even get away with the colloquial but incorrect "**were it me**".

But this, though correct, sounds like quite antiquated English, especially in speech.

Slightly more natural would be to say "...something, **if it were I**", but again, the incorrect but colloquial "**if it were me**" would sound even more natural.

Trouble is, even to use that last construction indicates knowledge of the subjunctive; everyone else you speak to will probably try and correct you to say "was", and if you contradict them you'll probably be marked for life as a pedant, and not welcome in anti-intellectual society.

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be "be it I".  But the whole phrase sounds somewhat peculiar: it might be better to rephrase, perhaps as "if I were in that situation".

Comment: And it would have to be future.  The only possible use I can think of is "They say some lucky person will win £20 million on the lottery tomorrow.  **Be it I**, I will leave my job."  On the whole, not a useful construction.

Comment: Thank you, Tim! May it be rephrased? For example, "I will leave my job, be it I who will win £20 million on the lottery tomorrow".

Comment: This usage requires the past subjunctive, not the present subjunctive (despite the fact that the action is taking place in the present). It should be "were it I".

Comment: @PeterShor: "Were it I who won", but "be it I who wins" [future, as I said]. And avrelian: I was emphasising how useless the phrase is. No matter how you *could* use it, please don't.

Comment: @Tim: Using "be" for the future sounds wrong to me. Of course, this form is virtually never used currently, so I could be utterly wrong about this. But it seems to me that the present subjunctive was used for counterfactual assertions about a continuing condition in the present, and not for the future. For example, "If this be treason ...", "If this be false and upon me proved ...", "Be thou a spirit of health or goblin damn'd ...", "If this be so ...". But maybe I'm wrong, and it was also used for the future. And I completely agree with Tim, don't use this construction.

Comment: @Peter: one last question. In my (contrived) example, would you really write "if it were I who wins"? (NB not won, where I agree with you).

Comment: @Tim: I would write "If I were to win the lottery tomorrow, I would leave my job." I believe the older style of phrasing would be "Were I to win the lottery tomorrow ..." Placing counterfactual clauses in the future can be done by using adverbs ("Were I crowned king tomorrow ...") or the "were to" construction ("Were I to be crowned king ...")

Answer (score 1):

I find it a strange sentence altogether. Does it mean *I would do something if it concerned only me, but it concerns other people as well, so I haven’t*? If so, you could say *I would do something, if it were only me. But it isn’t, so I've done nothing.*

Comment: Sorry for my vague explanation. Imagine a situation. Your friend tells you: "Hi! Yesterday I saw you in a crowd. You saw me too but suddenly ran away." And you reply to him: "I would surely greet you, be it me."

Comment: Then that is an impossible English sentence as far as I can see, at least in British Standard English. The normal response would be 'If it had been me, I would certainly have responded, I can assure you.'

Comment: And what about "be/were it I" (proposed by @TimLymington and @njd)?

Comment: I can't imagine anyone saying either.